# Tabulator. How to enable and disable editing from js

Tags: tabulator

I'm using tabulator (fantastic thing), which has a built in, in line editing functionality.

The thing is though, it's either on or off by having the editor tag on a column basis.
You can disable the editor for a given cell as well.

What I'm trying to do is to have the table displayed as read only so to say.
Then click on a 'edit' button (which is in my table and I capture the click). That would in turn enable the inline, built-in editor functionality for that raw only.
Then I click a save button, write the updated data back to my DB and make the row read-only again.

So, with tabulator 4.2, I'd be looking for something like

```
var usrtable = new Tabulator("#usrtable", {
        ajaxURL:"/account/cgi-bin/getallusers.php",
        resizableColumns:false,
        tooltips:true,
        history:true,
        pagination:"local",
        paginationSize:10,
        paginationSizeSelector:true,
        reactiveData:true,
        selectable:true,
        initialSort:[{column:"username", dir:"asc"},],
        columns:[
            { formatter: editIcon, width: 40, sortable: false, align: "center", cellClick:  function (e, cell) {
                    var id = cell.getRow().getData().id;
                    row(id).editable=true;
                    /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
                }
            },
            {title:"Id", field:"id", visible:false},
            {title:"Username", field:"username", width:80, editor:"input"},
            {title:"Password", field:"password", width:70, editor:"input"},
            {title:"Role", field:"role", width:70, align:"center", formatter:"plaintext", editor:"select", editorParams:{values:["user","admin"]}},
            {title:"Change passwd", field:"changepasswd", width:90,  align:"center", formatter:"tickCross", sorter:"boolean", editor:true},
        ],
    });
```

Is that somehow possible or do I have to re-invent the wheel? i.e. create a model to edit the data outside the table?

What I have tried.....
Once rendered, a cell looks like this:

```
<div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="username" tabindex="0" title="test" style="width: 80px; height: 29px;">test</div>
```

And when you click on the cell, it becomes editable and the class 'tabulator-editing' is added to the div.
So..... I though I could 'just' catch the click event and do something like this:

```
$(".tabulator-cell").on("click",function(){
        ($this).removeClass("tabulator-editing");
    });
```

that didn't work so tried this:

```
$(".tabulator-cell").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

that didn't work either.
When doing this:

```
$(".tabulator-cell").on("click",function(){
        alert("cell clicked");
    });
```

it actually never fires... :-(

Either I'm doing something wrong or really do not know where to go from here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I also got feedback from Oli who is the developer for Tabulator.

The short answer is that there is no option to enable editing at the row lever as I feared.
Furthermore, the option will not be added due to multiple factors.

In other words, what I'm trying to do is not available out of the box and the editing is to be done at the cell level.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also add the link where Oli gave you feedback? I would like to read it.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with Tabulator's [Optional Editing](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/edit#optional):

```
// column definition
{ title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", editable:editCheck }

var editCheck = function (cell) {
    var isEditable = cell.getRow().getElement().classList.contains('isEditable');
    return isEditable;
}
```

With this logic in place, you simply need to toggle `isEditable` class on the appropriate Tabulator Row.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation under Column Setup, there is a Data Manipulation option called `editable`.

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/columns#definition

`editable - callback to check if the cell is editable (see Manipulating Data for more details)`

I haven't experimented with it myself, but it appears as if this is only called when initially rendering the table, so you may have to force a re-render with `table.redraw(true)` when the user clicks the Edit and Save buttons.

You could also just use your `cellClick` event and call `cell.edit()`.

Comment: You need to set the editable to enable the editable. I could not find a way to set the editable on its own though.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean... However, you would do something like this

    `var usrtable = new Tabulator("#usrtable", {
        ...,
        columns:[
            { title: "test", field: "foo", editable: function(cell) { return true; } }.
        ]
    })`

You will want to put your own logic within the editable callback and return true or false depending if it should be editable.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The goal is to switch the editable on and off on the row level by a button click. There is way to set conditional editing but it's on the cell level as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `option` for this in the tabulator. But if you want to disable a cell from editing, you can simply remove all the tabulator applied classes for the particular cell. For eg., if you want to make the last row edit disabled, you can use something like this,

```
$(".tabulator-row:last .tabulator-cell").removeAttr("role tabulator-field tabindex title");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question but my answer can be useful for visitors come here (like me) in future..

We have also a similar requirements, and we ended up by this solution. We have added `"editor"` in every column with another attribute `"editable"`. In `"editable"`, we are checking whether the row is selected or not, if row is selected then field can be editable otherwise not editable.

Other than that we have also used a `"rowSelected"` and `"rowDeselected"` to show/hide save button and on `"rowSelected"`, we are checking that only 1 row is selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Per OneManBand's suggestion, you can use optional editing for this.

In your columns, you set `editable` to a function that checks if editmode is on or not:

```
{ title: 'Name', field: 'name', editor: true, editable: isEditMode }
```

Then you can let `setEditMode` check for a condition. This can be at the row level by checking what row the selected cell is in. Check the fiddle to see how.

```
function isEditMode(cell) {
    // Return true/false based on condition
    return false
    
    // To check the value of a particular cell, you can do:
    // console.log(cell._cell.row.cells[3].value)
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x387eoby/30/

*Note: In the fiddle, the toggling of editmode is bypassing editmode, by listening to the click handler instead. This way you can still toggle editmode while editmode is turned off.*